# Adding input elements and sub elements dynamically to form

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am using Javascript to dynamically create input fields in a form. I need to add same sub sub fields.
Like, if the user inputs 3, my script should create 3 input fields having their name attributes as Member 1, Member 2 and Member 3. And if the user inputs in Member 2 (sub), Member A and Member B.
And how do I access data from these fields in PHP using post method ? Please check code.

```js
 <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addFields(){
          
            var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
            
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
              container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i=0;i<number;i++){
            
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Q. " + (i+1)));
    
     var divtest = document.createElement("div");
     divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+(i+1));
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="content"><span>Question: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="question[]" value="" /></span>  <span>Marks: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="marks[]" value="" /></span>  <span>Question Page Index: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="question_page_index[]" value="" /></span></div>';
    container.appendChild(divtest);

    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  
    var divSubQ = document.createElement("div");
    divSubQ.innerHTML = '<div class="content"><span>Number of Sub Question: <input type="text" id="submember" name="submember" value=""></span>  <span><a href="#" id="Subfilldetails" onclick="addSubFields()">Fill Details</a></span> </div> <div id="subcontainer"/>';
    container.appendChild(divSubQ);
    
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        }
    </script>
 
  <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addSubFields(){
            var number = document.getElementById("submember").value;
            var subcontainer = document.getElementById("subcontainer");
            while (subcontainer.hasChildNodes()) {
               subcontainer.removeChild(subcontainer.lastChild);
            }
            for (i=0;i<number;i++){
                subcontainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Sub. Q. " + (i+1)));
     
     var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="content"><span>Question: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="question[]" value="" /></span>  <span>Marks: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="marks[]" value="" /></span>  <span>Question Page Index: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="question_page_index[]" value="" /></span></div>';
    subcontainer.appendChild(divtest);

    subcontainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  
    var divSubQ = document.createElement("div");
    divSubQ.innerHTML = '<div class="content"><span>Number of Sub Question: <input type="text" id="submember" name="submember" value=""></span>  <span><a href="#" id="Subfilldetails" onclick="addSubFields()">Fill Details</a></span> </div>';
    subcontainer.appendChild(divSubQ);
   }
       }
    </script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of members: (max. 10)<br />
    <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</a>
    <div id="container"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are creating the functions in a .js file, you dont need the `script` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the input fields in a form and then post it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

something like:

```
<form id="my-form" action="/your/url" method="post">
    // your fields go here
</form>
```

You add the inputs *inside* that form and then you submit it with a submit button. The action in the form is the URL that you capture in your php code

Answer (score 0):

Add following code at last in your addFields() function

```
var btn = document.createElement("input");
btn.setAttribute("type", "submit");
container.appendChild(btn);
```

and wrap `<div id="container"/>` in `<form>` tag like

```
<form action="">
<div id="container"/>
</form>
```

You need to set some id for each input field to uniquely identify the submitted data in `$_POST`.

Comment: Actually Ima not getting your proper flow. Each question have sub questions. But sub questions have sub-subquestions,..?? We generally use ID attribute for uniqueness. In your `addFields()` you need to do something for new generating ID's like `<div id="subcontainer'+(i+1)+'"/>` to uniquely identify that element.